# Powershell: How can I disable automatic int32 type conversions on math with integral numbers?

Tags: powershell, types, casting, type-conversion

This is an example, the real thing is a large `New-Object 'object[,]'` 2D array:

```
PS C:\> $a=[int16]10
PS C:\> $a.GetType().Name
Int16
PS C:\> $a++
PS C:\> $a.GetType().Name
Int32

PS C:\> $a=[int16]10
PS C:\> $a.GetType().Name
Int16
PS C:\> $a=$a+[int16]1
PS C:\> $a.GetType().Name
Int32
```

I can FORCE the type in such things, but this is actually a conversion after the math is done and slows down the the complete code by ~ 10%, so it is useless:

```
PS C:\> $a=[int16]10
PS C:\> $a.GetType().Name
Int16
PS C:\> $a=[int16]($a+1)
PS C:\> $a.GetType().Name
Int16
```

Is there no way to prevent this auto-conversion from byte and int16 to it's beloved int32 when using any math?

As for the comment of @mklement0 I extend the examples to the use case. Note that no value anywhere on that board exceeds "8":

```
# Init board
$BoardXSize = [int]100
$BoardYSize = [int]100
$Board = New-Object 'object[,]' $BoardXSize,$BoardYSize
for ($y=0;$y -lt $BoardYSize;$y++) {
    for ($x=0;$x -lt $BoardXSize;$x++) {
        [int16]$Board[$x,$y] = 0
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Int16
PS C:\> $Board[49,49]++
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Int32

PS C:\> [int16]$Board[49,49]=0
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Int16
PS C:\> [int16]$Board[49,49]++
0
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Int32

PS C:\> [int16]$Board[49,49]=0
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Int16
PS C:\> $Board[49,49] += [int16]1
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Int32

PS C:\> [byte]$Board[49,49]=0
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Byte
PS C:\> $Board[49,49] += [byte]1
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Int32
```

However when being EXTREMELY PICKY about the operators it works, just "++" seems to fail:

```
PS C:\> [int16]$Board[49,49]=0
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Int16
PS C:\> [int16]$Board[49,49] += [int16]1
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Int16

PS C:\> [byte]$Board[49,49]=0
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Byte
PS C:\> [byte]$Board[49,49] += [byte]1
PS C:\> ($Board[49,49]).GetType().Name
Byte
```

But since this is always a cast after the math was done it does not improve speed. But it is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ***type-constrain* your variable**, by placing the type literal to the *left* of the (initial) assignment:

```sh
# Note how [int16] is to the *left* of $a = ...
PS> [int16] $a = 10; ++$a; $a += 1; $a, $a.GetType().Name
12
Int16
```

Note that this works differently than typing a variable in a statically typed language such as C#, for example: Instead of locking in the specified type statically, a *cast* is performed *on every assignment* in order to coerce the value being assigned to that type.

For instance, with `[int16] $a = 10` having been the original assignment, `$a += 1` is effectively the same as assigning `[int16] ($a + 1)`.

This also implies that you're free to assign values of any type, as long as they can be *converted* to the constraining type; e.g.:

```sh
# These work, because they are implicitly cast (converted) to [int16]
$a += 1.2
$a += '42'
```

See the next section about arrays.

**Applying type constraints to *arrays*:**

To a (one-dimensional) *array*:

```sh
# Strongly types the array as storing [int16] instances
# *and* type-constrains the $arr variable.
PS> [int16[]] $arr = 10, 11; ++$arr[0]; $arr[1] += 1; $arr; $arr.ForEach('GetType').Name
11
12
Int16
Int16
```

To a *two*-dimensional *array* (rare in PowerShell):

```sh
# Strongly types the 2D array as storing [int16] instances,
# but does *not* type-constrain the $arr2d *variable.
PS> $countDim1, $countDim2 = 2, 3;
    $arr2d = [int16[,]]::new($countDim1, $countDim2);
    ++$arr2d[0,0]; $arr2d[0,0].GetType().Name
Int16
```

Note that this is truly creates strongly, statically typed .NET arrays, but assigning to their elements again applies PowerShell's flexible type conversions (e.g., `$arr[0] = '42'` works fine).

Also note that the 2D array example, for brevity, doesn't actually type-constrain the data type of the *variable*, given that there's no type literal to the left of the assignment; therefore, you could still replace the entire array with an arbitrary new value of any type (e.g., `$arr2d = 'foo'`); to perform type-constraining too, you'd have to do:

```sh
# Creates a 2D [int16] array *and* type-constrains $arr2D to
# such arrays.
[int16[,]] $arr2d = [int16[,]]::new($countDim1, $countDim2)
```

Finally, note that you cannot type-constrain *individual elements* of an array or (writable) *properties* of an object; in other words: only L-values that are *PowerShell variables* can be type-constrained;<sup>[1]</sup> in all other cases a simple ad hoc *cast* is performed; e.g., given an `[object[]]` array `$a = 1, 2`, the following two statements are equivalent:

```sh
# Cast
$a[0] = [int] 42 

# !! A mere cast too, because the assignment target is an 
# !! *array element*, which cannot be type-constrained.
[int] $a[0] = 42
```

---

Also unlike languages such as C#, **PowerShell automatically *widens* types in numerical operations**.

This widening apples not just to operands of *differing* (numeric) types, but also if the result would be too large to fit into the (larger of the two) input type(s), and it has two surprising aspects:

- A *minimum* width of `[int]` (`System.Int32`) is applied, which means that types smaller than `[int]` are *always* widened to `[int]` in the result, even if it isn't necessary, as you've observed:

  ```sh
  # Implicitly widens to [int], even though not necessary.
  # Note that the [byte] cast is only applied to the LHS
  PS> ([byte] 42 + 1).GetType().Name
  Int32
  ```
- If the result is too large to fit into the (larger of the two) input type(s), the result is invariably widened to a `[double]` (`System.Double`)(!)

  ```sh
  # Implicitly widens to [double](!), because adding 1
  # to the max. [int] value doesn't fit into an [int].
  PS> ([int]::MaxValue + 1).GetType().Name
  Double

  # NO widening, because the large input type is a [long] (System.Int64)
  # (suffix L), so the result fits into a [long] too.
  PS> ([long] [int]::MaxValue + 1).GetType().Name
  Int64
  ```
- This immediate widening to `[double]` in expressions, without considering larger *integer* types, differs from how number *literals* are parsed in PowerShell, where larger integer types *are* used (but note that PowerShell never chooses *unsigned* types):

  ```sh
  # 2147483648 = [int]::MaxValue + 1, so [long] (System.Int64)
  # is chose as the literal's type. 
  (2147483648).GetType().Name
  In64
  ```

  - Note that number literals can also have *type suffixes* to explicitly designate their type, such as `l` for `[long]` and `d` for `[decimal]`; e.g., `2147483648d.GetType().Name` returns `Decimal`.

---

##### Optional reading: Performance of accessing array elements in strongly typed vs. untyped (`[object[]]`) arrays:

PowerShell's regular array type, as created by `,` and the `@(...)` operator, for instance, is `[object[]]`, i.e. an "untyped" array in that `[object]`, as the root of the .NET type hierarchy, can store values of any data type - even allowing for mixing of different types in a given, single array.

While this affords great flexibility, it affects:

- Type safety: Depending on the use case, ensuring that all elements have the same type may be required; if so, use a strongly typed array.
- Memory efficiency: Value-type instances must be wrapped in `[object]` instances for storage, a process known as *boxing*, and,  on access, requires unwrapping, known as *unboxing*.
- Runtime performance: Surprisingly, unlike what the overhead of boxing and unboxing suggests, there is *little to no* performance benefit to strong typing, and with 2D arrays performance can even suffer.

Below are the results of **benchmarking** array get and set access, comparing 1D and 2D arrays with various value types vs. `object` elements:

- 15 runs were averaged, with 1-million-element 1D arrays and 1000 x 1000 2D arrays.
- The benchmark source code is further below.

  - To run the code yourself, you need to first download and define function `Time-Command` from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27).
  - Assuming you have looked at the linked Gist's source code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can install it directly as follows:

    ```sh
    irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27/raw/Time-Command.ps1 | iex
    ```
  - **Benchmarking in PowerShell is far from an exact science**; since the benchmarks are wall clock-based, it is best to average multiple runs and to ensure that the system isn't (too) busy running other things.
- The absolute timings will vary based on many factors, but the `Factor` column should provide a sense of relative performance - differences in the 2nd decimal places are likely to be *incidental* (e.g., `1.00` vs. `1.03`) and such rankings may swap places in repeated invocations.
- **Some conclusions from the results below**, which were run on *PowerShell (Core) 7.2.2* on a Windows 10 machine - *Windows PowerShell* performance characteristics *may differ*:

  - 1D arrays (by far the most common type of array in PowerShell):

    - *Getting* is *marginally* faster if strongly typed.
    - *Updating* is noticeably faster if strongly typed.
  - 2D arrays (rare in PowerShell):

    - *Getting* is *somewhat slower* if strongly typed.
    - *Updating* is *somewhat faster* if strongly typed.
  - Note: While there are no Windows PowerShell results below, in my tests **it seems that the speed of array access roughly *doubled* in PowerShell (Core) 7+**.

```
# Sample results on a Windows 10 machine running PowerShell 7.2.2

============== 1D: GET performance (avg. of 15 runs)

Factor Secs (15-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------ -------
1.00   0.482              # [byte[]]…
1.00   0.483              # [int[]] (Int32)…
1.01   0.487              # [long[]]…
1.02   0.492              # [int16[]]…
1.08   0.521              # [decimal[]]…
1.09   0.526              # [object[]]…
1.11   0.533              # [double[]]…
1.12   0.537              # [datetime[]]…

============== 1D: SET (INCREMENT) performance (avg. of 15 runs)

Factor Secs (15-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------ -------
1.00   0.526              # [double[]]…
1.03   0.541              # [int[]] (Int32)…
1.11   0.584              # [long[]]…
1.30   0.681              # [byte[]]…
1.40   0.738              # [int16[]]…
1.57   0.826              # [decimal[]]…
1.86   0.975              # [object[]], no casts…
2.90   1.523              # [object[]] with [int] casts…
7.34   3.857              # [datetime[]]…

============== 2D: GET performance (avg. of 15 runs)

Factor Secs (15-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------ -------
1.00   0.620              # [object[,]]…
1.13   0.701              # [double[,]]…
1.13   0.702              # [int[,]] (Int32)…
1.18   0.731              # [datetime[,]]…
1.20   0.747              # [long[,]]…
1.23   0.764              # [byte[,]]…
1.26   0.782              # [decimal[,]]…
1.34   0.828              # [int16[,]]…

============== 2D: SET (INCREMENT) performance (avg. of 15 runs)

Factor Secs (15-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------ -------
1.00   0.891              # [double[,]]…
1.02   0.904              # [long[,]]…
1.10   0.977              # [byte[,]]…
1.24   1.107              # [object[,]], no casts…
1.27   1.131              # [int16[,]]…
1.28   1.143              # [int[,]] (Int32)…
1.46   1.300              # [decimal[,]]…
1.72   1.530              # [object[,]] with [int] casts…
5.25   4.679              # [datetime[,]]…
```

**Benchmark source code**:

```sh
$runs = 15 # how many run to average.
$d1 = $d2 = 1000  # 1000 x 1000 2D array
$d = $d1 * $d2    # 1 million-element 1D array

# index arrays for looping
$indices_d1 = 0..($d1 - 1)
$indices_d2 = 0..($d2 - 1)
$indices = 0..($d - 1)

# 1D arrays.
$ao = [object[]]::new($d)
$ab = [byte[]]::new($d)
$ai16 = [int16[]]::new($d)
$ai = [int[]]::new($d)
$al = [long[]]::new($d)
$adec = [decimal[]]::new($d)
$ad = [double[]]::new($d)
$adt = [datetime[]]::new($d)

# 2D arrays.
$ao_2d = [object[,]]::new($d1, $d2)
$ab_2d = [byte[,]]::new($d1, $d2)
$ai16_2d = [int16[,]]::new($d1, $d2)
$ai_2d = [int[,]]::new($d1, $d2)
$al_2d = [long[,]]::new($d1, $d2)
$adec_2d = [decimal[,]]::new($d1, $d2)
$ad_2d = [double[,]]::new($d1, $d2)
$adt_2d = [datetime[,]]::new($d1, $d2)

"`n============== 1D: GET performance (avg. of $runs runs)"

Time-Command -Count $runs `
{ # [object[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $null = $ao[$i] }
},
{ # [byte[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $null = $ab[$i] }
}, 
{ # [int16[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $null = $ai16[$i] }
},
{ # [int[]] (Int32)
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $null = $ai[$i] }
},
{ # [long[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $null = $al[$i] }
}, 
{ # [decimal[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $null = $adec[$i] }
}, 
{ # [double[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $null = $ad[$i] }
},
{ # [datetime[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $null = $adt[$i] }
} | Format-Table Factor, Secs*, Command

"============== 1D: SET (INCREMENT) performance (avg. of $runs runs)"

Time-Command -Count $runs `
{ # [object[]], no casts
  foreach ($i in $indices) { ++$ao[$i] }
},
{ # [object[]] with [int] casts
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $ao[$i] = [int] ($ao[$i] + 1) }
},
{ # [byte[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { ++$ab[$i] }
}, 
{ # [int16[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { ++$ai16[$i] }
},
{ # [int[]] (Int32)
  foreach ($i in $indices) { ++$ai[$i] }
},
{ # [long[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { ++$al[$i] }
},
{ # [decimal[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { ++$adec[$i] }
},
{ # [double[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { ++$ad[$i] }
},
{ # [datetime[]]
  foreach ($i in $indices) { $adt[$i] += 1 } # ++ not supported
} | Format-Table Factor, Secs*, Command

"============== 2D: GET performance (avg. of $runs runs)"

Time-Command -Count $runs `
{ # [object[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $null = $ao_2d[$i, $j] }
  }
},
{ # [byte[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $null = $ab_2d[$i, $j] } 
  }
},
{ # [int16[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $null = $ai16_2d[$i, $j] }
  }
}, 
{ # [int[,]] (Int32)
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $null = $ai_2d[$i, $j] }
  }
},
{ # [long[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $null = $al_2d[$i, $j] } 
  }
}, 
{ # [decimal[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $null = $adec_2d[$i, $j] } 
  }
},
{ # [double[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $null = $ad_2d[$i, $j] } 
  }
}, 
{ # [datetime[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $null = $adt_2d[$i, $j] } 
  }
} | Format-Table Factor, Secs*, Command

"============== 2D: SET (INCREMENT) performance (avg. of $runs runs)"

Time-Command -Count $runs `
{ # [object[,]], no casts
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { ++$ao_2d[$i, $j] }
  }
},
{ # [object[,]] with [int] casts
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $ao_2d[$i, $j] = [int] ($ao_2d[$i, $j] + 1) }
  }
}, 
{ # [byte[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { ++$ab_2d[$i, $j] }
  }
}, 
{ # [int16[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { ++$ai16_2d[$i, $j] }
  }
},
{ # [int[,]] (Int32)
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { ++$ai_2d[$i, $j] }
  }
},
{ # [long[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { ++$al_2d[$i, $j] }
  }
}, 
{ # [decimal[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { ++$adec_2d[$i, $j] } 
  }
},
{ # [double[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { ++$ad_2d[$i, $j] } 
  }
},
{ # [datetime[,]]
  foreach ($i in $indices_d1) {
    foreach ($j in $indices_d2) { $adt_2d[$i, $j] += 1 } # ++ not supported
  }
} | Format-Table Factor, Secs*, Command
```

---

<sup>[1] The reason is that type-constraining requires attaching a type-conversion attribute to a PowerShell variable object.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that indeed works for simple variables, even when using `[byte]$a = 1 ; $a++`. But I did not notice when I tried since I need it for a 2D array where it sadly does not work. I'll extend my question.

Comment: I could apply your hints to force `[byte]` or `[int16]` to my use case at https://github.com/Joachim-Otahal/Bosch-Sandgrain-Challenge - Your answer helped, but sadly still does hurt improve performance by ~10% due to that automatic widening + casting still happening somewhere when using an array,

Comment: Oh, thanks for your update, but my array is "the other type" for speed reasons :). Using the `$array[0][0]` type makes it MUCH slower.

Comment: @JoachimOtahal, speed is always a concern in PowerShell, but note that you should construct your 2D array as a strongly typed array, which both speeds up array access overall and obviates the need for casts when updating elements; please see my update, but the short of it is: construct your 2D arrays as `[int16[,]]::new($BoardXSize,$BoardYSize)`

Comment: Thanks for the last update! But the weird part is: `$Board = [object[,]]::new($BoardXSize,$BoardYSize)` is still faster than `$Board = [int32[,]]::new($BoardXSize,$BoardYSize)` even though is it the datatype powershell chooses for itself. Maybe it does an extra int32<->int32 casting somewhere... :D. Thank you for your time! PS: using int16 or byte still makes it slower too.

Comment: @JoachimOtahal, good point re performance - I got curious and decided to run benchmarks on strongly typed vs. "untyped" (`[object[]]`, `[object[,]]`) arrays - please see my update (bottom section) - you may still opt for strong typing if you want to avoid having to cast explicitly on every update of an element.